# AgitarOne cannot connect to localhost:8080/agitar-server on eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

I am using AgitarOne to create for junit testing I followed their installation and was able to install it but my problem is that whenever i try to run my junit testing it returns an error "unable to connect to localhost:8080/agitar-server/". I know that localhost:8080/agitar-server is available since I am opening it in my browser but it still throws that error. The JUnit testing is run via eclipse as AgitarOne has an eclipse plugin.

I might have missed some configuration problem here in eclipse as this is a fresh install.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check your eclipse configuration "windows->preference->agitar server" make sure that host is "localhost" and port is 8080.